# Syntax for SQL statement using mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public void insertTags(Elements[] elements) {

    Connection con = (Connection) DbConnection.getConnection();

    try {
        String sql = "insert into htmltags(source) values(?),(?),(?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, elements[0].toString());
        ps.setString(2, elements[1].toString());
        ps.setString(3, elements[2].toString());
        int rs = ps.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Data inserted" + rs);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

is this a valid syntax for Prepared statement.

Comment: You can't insert 3 values into one column "source", and the syntax would need to be `values(?,?,?)`.

Comment: What is `values(?),(?),(?)`

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
int rs = ps.executeUpdate(sql);
```

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) we see that `PreparedStatement#executeUpdate()` does not take any parameters.  The reason is that we already passed the query earlier when preparing the statement.  Your code should be this:

```
int rs = ps.executeUpdate();  // no parameter
```

Also no need to cast the result of `prepareStatement` to `PrepareStatement`

Comment: Of note, many tutorials also seem to make this mistake (e.g. MkYong, at least as of several months ago when I last checked).

Comment: in fact its incorrect here. Maybe youre trying to concatenate values. In that case only use one placeholder and concatenate in the java code...

Answer (score 0):

To insert multiple values, I don't thing using `values(?),(?),(?)` is the right syntax, instead use a loop, or for better way you can use **batch** :

```
String sql = "insert into htmltags(source) values(?)";
try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);) {
    for (Elements element : elements) {
        ps.setString(1, element.toString());
        ps.addBatch();//Add a new batch for each Element
    }

    int[] result = ps.executeBatch();//Submits a batch of commands to the database

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```